# Many BSODs - where to look for the explanation?

Tags: crash, bsod, diagnostic

I have recently been getting a lot of blue screens of death with various errors (see [this](http://pastebin.com/cm6HNx2Q) for a crash report created with the WhoCrashed software). The many MEMORY_MANAGEMENT errors made me think it had to be a RAM error (I have 2x4gb DDR3 RAM), so I've been running some Memtests. The [first run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhByl.jpg) gave 1 error in 18 hours, the [second run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKTqt.jpg) gave 4 errors in 10,5 hours. However, when I remove either of the two RAM sticks and run Memtest on only the remaining 4gb, then I have not been able to reproduce any errors within 2x9 hours of running time. So I was suggested that this is not because of the RAM but could be due to a cheap power supply. But given my specifications below and the crash reports I've attached, is the power supply what I should be looking at?

I'm running Windows 8.1 and my hardware specifications are as follows:

- Corsair CX 600W PSU
- Intel Core i5-3570 Processor, Socket-LGA1155, Quad Core, 3.4GHz
- MSI B75MA-P45, Socket-1155, m-ATX, B75, DDR3, 1xG3-PCIe-x16, SATA 6Gb/s, USB 3
- Crucial DDR3 BallistiX Sport 1600MHz 8GB
- Radeon HD 7800
- Kingston HyperX 3K SSD 120GB 2.5"
- Seagate Barracuda HDD 2TB

Results from [CPU-Z](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35961027/cpuz.html).

Comment: Cheap power supplies can definitely cause major issues. Perhaps when your GPU gets to work your machine can't hack it and weirdness follows. Try reducing your screen resolution to minimum or something to get that GPU load down. See if you can leave the system running fairly idle. CX PSUs are worthy of replacement.

Comment: @Doc: What do you mean by "can't hack it"? Not sure I understand what I would achieve by your suggestion. The crashes have occured most frequently when running something with a lot of graphics (the temperatures of the cpu and gpu are ok).

Comment: As your graphics card works harder and harder, it consumes more and more power. Therefore increasing the load on your power supply. You already pointed out that it's a cheap PSU. So I'm suggesting it can't handle the load, through it's trying and the short-comings of it are where your problems come from. Can you try another PSU? Does this ever fail when the machine isn't doing anything?

Comment: It has crashed a couple of times where the computer has been fairly idle, but it has mostly been during games with a lot of graphics. I don't have any other PSU, but if this is the most likely thing causing the problem, then I better get my hands on one.

Comment: It seems like the most likely culprit. Your memory tests could be indicative of a motherboard problem. But single-bit errors can happen and while I've never directly seen it, I suspect your memory is in fact fine. Anyway, the obvious place to start is the PSU. Maybe buy one from a place where you can return it if necessary.

Comment: I have an almost similar system configuration. Same CPU, same PSU, also an SSD and a 2TB Seagate disk. My GFX is a GTX 660 Ti. I have never had any issues with the power supply not delivering enough power, and my system has been in use for over a year. Perhabs your GFX is different, as you did not specify it in the question, but if you're running GFX with similar power consumption, I don't think that's your issue. Or you have faulty hardware, at least.

Comment: Run CPU-Z and look at the **SPD** tab.  Compare all the timing numbers for both memory chips are all the number identical?  Then goto the **Memory** tab and compare the timings numbers at the nearest speed under the **SPD** tab.  Post the results.

Comment: @Kristian, cybernard: Thanks for your reply. My GFX is a Radeon HD 7800. I'll run CPU-Z later tonight and post the results. Thank you.

Comment: @cybernard: They look the same. See the results in the updated post.

Comment: @StefanHansen your **Command Rate** is wrong! Your memory chips only support 2T and your motherboard's BIOS is set to 1T.  Change the **Command Rate** to 2T in the BIOS and test again.

Comment: @cybernard: Good catch. I'll let you know if this solves my issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your PSU (if functioning correctly) should be able to handle the kit that you listed. However, you mention the problem is worse during graphics intensive work - do you also have a discrete graphics card? These will usually be as demanding or more demanding than the CPU.

While you are considering power, you might also want to consider heat - are any of your components getting hot? Have you got [RealTemp](http://www.techpowerup.com/realtemp/) or other monitoring running?

But on to your RAM, a 9hr stint is usually enough for MemTest to demonstrate a problem, but it can take longer... can you afford to run a test for 12-24hrs? But it is also not uncommon to have problems with 2 or 4 sticks where a lesser number don't have problems. For example, I had a mobo that could take 4 sticks and supported 4GB sticks, but didn't work with most sets of 4 x 4GB sticks. You should check with MSI to confirm that your RAM is officially supported. If your combination of RAM is supported, can you try the RAM in a different machine? Ultimately, if there are any doubts about the RAM, RMA them - Crucial sticks will have a 10yr to 'lifetime' warranty.

Another ripe cause of BSODs are dodgy drivers - have you updated your drivers recently? Particular chipset and gfx drivers.

In short, the problem could be anywhere - so how do you pin this down? I'm afraid, unless you get a) inspired or b) lucky, you are going to have to go through a laborious process of trial & error. I would strip your PC down to mobo/single RAM/boot drive, but nothing else. Boot up and run some stress tests (e.g. [Orthos](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Benchmarks/Orthos-Prime.shtml) for CPU and/or [Furmark](http://www.ozone3d.net/benchmarks/fur/) for GPU). Assuming continued successful outcomes, continue to add addition components - perhaps the GFX next, followed by additional RAM and disks. When you eventually break it, keep the last component added, but remove something else... e.g. keep additional RAM but remove GFX. Keep going until you narrow it down.

Comment: I agree with you that he is going to have to do some guess and check, but I disagree with your assertion that the PSU isn't an issue. 

When you see random error bits of in memtest over a 10 hours, I almost always check the PSU - Typically that means that mains voltage has flickered a bit and the PSU passed it on to the system. 

In addition to this, the CX series has been pretty universally criticized for being unsuitable for any high end systems due to it's inability to handle unreliable input voltage.  

I bet dollars to doughnuts it's his power supply.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Not sure what is meant by a discrete graphics card, but I have a Radeon HD 7800 which should be fine with this computer, I think. I have been watching temperatures in both the CPU and GPU and they seem fine. I've updated the driver for my GFX and I've run the Intel Driver Update Utility which doesn't find any new drivers. Is there anything else I should update? I think I want to try and force a crash by running FurMark/Orthos, because I find it weird that I can't consistently replicate errors in memtest (isn't that an indication that it issomething else than RAM?)

Comment: I haven't discounted a PSU problem - but that rig, including the gfx card, will draw less than half of what that PSU can deliver - approx 300W (peak). Of course, the problem could be quality of supply rather than quantity. If the OP has the resources, swapping out other components should prove/disprove this.

Comment: I tried putting the RAM into the two other sockets (both black) and ran a memtest over night. I got 81 errors. Does this talk in favor of it being the RAM that is faulty? Or doesn't it say anything?

Comment: The next two logical steps are to test the RAM in another rig, and/or test different RAM in your rig. You could argue that you should use the onboard graphics temporarily to remove the PSU load of the discreet card, if you want to reduce the likelihood of the PSU being a factor.

Note: does your Mobo say anything specific about which RAM slots should be used in which combinations - sometimes they can be very specific.